# C# constructor using collection generic with two parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I am creating a code that takes in the address and the sqft of the address. I am using a list and collections generic. It only returns house+place six times. Please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class House
{
    class place
    {
        public string address { get; set; }

        public int sqft { get; set; }

        public place(string address, int sqft)
        {
            this.address = address;
            this.address = address;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<place> places = new List<place>();


        places.Add(new place("lewis Rd.", 2001));
        places.Add(new place("mike Rd.", 1500));
        places.Add(new place("deseree St.", 1250));
        places.Add(new place("bottle Dr.", 2500));
        places.Add(new place("pen St.", 1100));
        places.Add(new place("walton St.", 999));

        for (int i = 0; i < places.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}\n", places[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this occurs in other code you are not showing or maybe you did not re-compile after encountering the error and had since altered your code. What you have here should compile without problem....

Comment: Indeed, this code compiles fine - although I *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, and note that your constructor assigns to one property twice and the other not at all.

Comment: Your code runs fine without any exceptions....

Comment: Sorry I changed my code a little bit and then it compiled. I tried to change my question but it wouldn't allow me to . Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it wouldn't allow me to"? What happened when you tried? You should always be able to edit your question. (In future, a [mcve] would be better, by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not get the constructor error, but there are two issues that need to be addressed.

Your Console.Write line isn't specifying which properties you want to output and should be closer to this...

```
Console.Write(" {0} has {1} square feet\n", places[i].address, places[i].sqft);
```

You are also assigning the address twice...

```
this.address = address;
this.address = address;
```

... when you probably wanted

```
this.address = address;
this.sqft = sqft;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Thats exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking it was something with my class Place.